# Any benefit to air sealing fixture boxes in cathedral ceiling? If so, ideal method?

Tags: electrical, moisture, energy-efficiency

New house. We have a cathedral ceiling. Foam vent baffles from eave to ridge, r-38 fiberglass (unfaced), sheetrock.

Most of the lights in the ceiling are LED puck lights that have a built in gasket to seal the opening. However, we have a few regular fixture boxes such as this ceiling fan box:

[image]

Would there be much to gain from air sealing this? If so, suggested method? I was thinking of masking it off and just giving it a good spray of flex seal. Worth the effort? Any reason NOT to?

Comment: I'd say that sealing from _dampness_ should be useful. I can imagine that small amounts of a typical "white goo" silicone sealant could do a reasonable job of sealing any openings here. It's easy to remove without much trace if needed. IANA certified civil engineer, though.

Comment: Is replacing the box an option? Arlington makes gasketed fixture boxes in a variety of styles....

Comment: @9000 I got out the caulk gun and...that worked pretty well, actually! And less messy than flex seal.

Comment: and way cheaper!